# How to login Facebook in child fragment, it's fragment inside fragment - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, facebook, google-signin

I am using `BottomNavigation` and `Tablayout`, and the TabLayout position is inside BottomNavigation fragment, so I want to Activated `OnActivityResult` for Facebook Login, but it's doesn't work because my `child fragment` had a parent of Fragment, not Activity //this is function when your parent is Activity

**Fragment**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Facebook
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try {
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.d("Activity", "ON RESULT CALLED");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
}
```

When your parent is Fragment?